# Create Octopus machine via REST API (PowerShell)

Tags: api, rest, powershell, octopus-deploy

I’m trying to create a machine via the REST API, calling it through PowerShell.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/wiki/Machines), only the name and thumbprint of the machine are needed to create a machine. But everything I try leads to either 405 or 500 errors:

```
$newMachine = @{Name='machineName';Thumbprint='asdvblsafghkvadc';} | ConvertTo-Json
$webClient.UploadString('http://server/octopus/api/machines','POST',$newMachine)

### OR

$newMachine = @{Name='machineName';Thumbprint='asdvblsafghkvadc';Roles='[web-server]';EnvironmentIds='[Environment-12]'; | ConvertTo-Json
$webClient.UploadString('http://server/octopus/api/machines','POST',$newMachine)
```

Creating environments and editing machines work perfectly, I just can’t get this machine creation down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a machine from the Octopus REST API, certain libraries need to imported. Dalmiro Grañas outlines this in the first of a series of blog posts on [interfacing with Octopus through PowerShell](https://dalmirogranias.wordpress.com/2014/09/19/octopus-api-and-powershell-getting-the-libraries-and-connecting-to-octopus/)

He does not cover creating machines though, this is something I had to figure out myself from the library documentation on the [MachineResource class](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Octopus.Client/Octopus.Client/MachineResource)

Below is the code I wound up using to create machines:

```
#Adding libraries
Add-Type -Path 'C:\OctopusLibraries\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\OctopusLibraries\Octopus.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\OctopusLibraries\Octopus.Platform.dll'

#Setting variables
$apikey = 'API-QBGAAZEUMSUKJVSADFSDFA5Y2FLC'
$OctopusURI = 'http://OctopusServer/octopus/api/'

#Creating a connection
$endpoint = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusServerEndpoint $OctopusURI,$apikey
$repository = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusRepository $endpoint

#Set the machine properties
$Properties = @{Name="MachineName";Thumbprint="1AE1B6F81A30C2C5771AC5B234S4FE975";EnvironmentIds="Environments-65";Roles="web-server";URI="https://MyServer:10933/";CommunicationStyle="TentaclePassive"}

$envObj = New-Object Octopus.Client.Model.MachineResource -Property $Properties
$repository.Machines.Create($envObj)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I had *assumed* that these libraries were included in your snippet. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

The post mentioned by ShaneC its a bit old by now. I recommend anyone trying to do this in Powershell to check the Module I started writing for Octopus Deploy.

Module site: http://octoposh.net/

Example of adding a machine using the module: https://github.com/Dalmirog/OctoPosh/wiki/Creating-Resources#machines

The module is still a work in progress, but I've been getting quite a good feedback of it lately.

With some help and feedback from the community, I'm sure It'll be end up being really good :)

Answer (score 1):

*Usually* when you're adding the tentacle agent to your server, immediately afterwards you'd want to register said tentacle to the desired Octopus server. I would supply you with the PowerShell code that I used to do such a task, however it's probably worth reading [the Octopus blog post on how they create their tentacle army](http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/auto-provision-ec2-instances-with-tentacle-installed). They supply the PowerShell and that was great start on how to do it.

Note: I had a terrible time of getting the tentacles to connect AFTER registering with the Octopus Server. The secret to getting it working? [Stop the tentacle service and start it again.](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/26441-issue-registering-tentacles)

---

After rereading your post, it looks like you're trying to add a tentacle to an Octopus server *outside* or after the tentacle installation itself. Can you clarify? I would think that at a minimum an environmentids and squid would be a requirement as well. Try adding the squid.

Comment: Our environments cannot connect to the internet, they are completely sandboxed off. When registering an environment through the UI, Octopus opens a connection to our environment. The problem is that the environment cannot open a connection to the Octopus server. I have already tried doing this from the environment itself, the call to 'tentacle.exe register-with' in the link you provided fails with our setup. Therefore I need to use the REST API to register the machine with the server

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this at work this week, here is an example of the code you are looking for (you will need PowerShell v3.0 to use Invoke-RestMethod, download for Windows 7 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595 [before MS went spyware]):

```
$headers = @{"X-Octopus-ApiKey"="<YOUR OCTOPUS API KEY>"} 
$url = "http://<YOUR OCTOPUS SERVER>/api/"

$envname = "<YOUR ENVIRONMENT NAME FROM OCTOPUS>"
$machine = "<YOUR MACHINE NAME>"
$dropPath = "\\<DROP MACHINE>\drop"
$appPath = "C:\Application"
$octopusPath = "C:\Octopus"
$roles = {"role1", "role2"}

# Get list of Environments
$environments = Invoke-RestMethod ($url + "environments/all") -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Choose the specific Environment by Name
$environmentId = $environments | ? { $_.Name -eq $envname }

# Fix up slashes
$dropPath = $dropPath.Replace("\","\\")
$appPath = $appPath.Replace("\","\\")
$octopusPath = $octopusPath.Replace("\","\\")

# build request
$body = "{""Endpoint"":{""CommunicationStyle"":""OfflineDrop"",""DropFolderPath"":""" + $dropPath + """,""ApplicationsDirectory"":""" + $appPath + """,""OctopusWorkingDirectory"":""" + $octopusPath + """},""Status"":""Unknown"",""Name"":""" + $machine + """,""EnvironmentIds"":[""" + $environmentId + """],""Roles"":[" + $roles + "]}"

# send request
$added = Invoke-RestMethod ($url + "machines") -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method Post

# show result
echo $added
```

I used similar code at work which I've tested, though I haven't got Octopus running at home (it's not that great of a product, I am forced to work with it and given the choice, I'd use alternate release control, means [Team Foundation and vNext build system specifically], the UI isn't great, the API isn't great and the value it adds in the form of release management is questionable for someone already working with TeamFoundation which provides everything required in a more accessible form for developers).

Still people have taken to it and it's not going away.